# Wiring my internet

Tags: internet, wireless-router, cat6, coaxial

I have Verizon internet service and am currently using wifi. My router is in the basement and my desktop computer is 2 floors and on the other side of the house above it... Worst possible positioning but that's just how things worked out. My wireless currently is extremely unstable so I've decide to correct the problem by wiring my computer directly.

The problem lies here: when redoing the room next to it (when the wall was open) we went ahead and wired some coaxial cable from our attic to our basement (with plenty of slack on both ends, don't ask me why we didn't go ahead and wire a CAT6 cable).

The question is: Can I use the coaxial cable to bring me internet connection? Naturally the router (which needs to stay where it is) takes a coaxial cable input and has Ethernet outputs. So maybe I would have to take a ethernet cable, convert to coaxial-coaxial to my computer, convert back to ethernet. Is this even possible to convert from coaxial to ethernet? Or do I have to attempt to go ahead and fish a cat6 cable through my house.

I cannot just split the signal because that would require two routers and two networks (which I don't believe would work with one cable-one ISP correct me if I'm wrong).

Thanks

Comment: Do people closer need the modem over there? If not, you could plug the Coax into the house into the one up to your room, and serve the house from up there.

Comment: yeah we do need to leave the modem down there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run ethernet over coax, and while I don't have any direct experience of doing this, you should be able to get reasonable speeds.  You are looking for an `Ethernet Over Coax Converter`.

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_coax

A web search will find many vendors of coax to ethernet converters that support standard 75ohm coax, such as this one: http://www.comnet.net/comnet-products/valueline.html

Another alternative would be to use the existing coax cable to "pull" a Cat6 cable through from the basement.  Tape the cat6 to the end of the coax and pull it up.  Make sure you tape it well so that

1. It doesn't snag on anything when you pull it
2. It doesn't come loose

(this is obviously a risky proposal, but you might consider it worth it)

Comment: @sawdust Current coax/ethernet converters support 75ohm.  Yes, it is risky to pull a new cable, but the answer to this question is going to be either "no" or something hacky.

Answer (score 1):

[Power line networking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_line_communication#Home_networking_.28LAN.29) might be a good alternative for your situation.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing! Thanks for the recommendation!